# code runs differently with/without breakpoint

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a user form (with SAVE button that writes to Excel sheet and RETURN button that goes back to a splash page) and want to set/check a flag if there are unsaved changes on the form.  I'm getting different functionality of the code depending on whether a breakpoint is set or not.

Here is the relevant portion of code:

```
Public saveFlag as Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    
    initializeCMAValues Me
    initializeTeamValues Me, getRowNum("CMA", "Team", False)
    ' getRowNum is a function that returns the row to read from
    ' in this case, the row with name=CMA, type=Team, createRow=False

    saveFlag = False
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Return_Click()
    ' Check for unsaved data
    If saveFlag Then
        If MsgBox("You have unsaved information on the form.  Do you wish to save it?", vbYesNo, "Unsaved Data") = vbYes Then
            btn_Save_Click
        End If
    End If

    ' Return to splash form
    Unload Me
    Form_Splash.Show
End Sub
```

If I enter the form and select RETURN, I get the msgbox prompt.  If I set a breakpoint at the `saveFlag = False` line, enter form, select RETURN (invoking breakpoint), continue running, then it runs as I would expect (i.e., no msgbox).

Instead of a public saveFlag variable, I've tried writing the flag to a non-visible label on the form; I've also tried writing to a cell on the Excel sheet.  Both gave the same results of this different behavior with and without the breakpoint.

I've also run the code with the initializeTeamValues line commented out and then the code runs fine.  I've triple checked that this subroutine only fills values into the textboxes on the form, nothing else.

Some research turned up a vague answer related to OLE pushing values onto the stack.  I then tried putting the "saveFlag = False" line at the beginning of the subroutine.  Same results.

Ideas of why the varying behavior?  Is there a better/alternate way to check for unsaved data?

Comment: Unsure what the specific problem is, but you might want to give [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) a read about why `Unload Me` and `Form_Splash.Show` aren't the best practice.

Comment: Replace `Unload Me` with `Me.Hide`. `Unload` means to remove the form object from memory which is a bad idea while the form is still active.